# function php to find html color by name

Tags: php, html, function, colors

I would like to know if they is a function in php to find html color by name?

Something like:

```
function getcolorcode($colorname) 
{
    $colorname = 
}
```

Comment: You're asking somebody to write a function for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should crawl this page  : http://htmlcss.wikia.com/wiki/Color_Codes
Or see if you can database of colors codes and color names.

Comment: Tank you i do this comment, i set the colors hex on my DB and consult before make the selection.